# Computer charger disconnects and reconnects repetitively when playing WoW

Tags: windows-8.1, charger

Whenever I play World of Warcraft, my computer's charger disconnects and connects again without rest. For some reason, this makes the frame rate drop and the game lags badly, and therefore goes unplayable, for a few seconds. As this is repeated without and end I can't play with the charger plugged in. Could it be something wrong with the computer, charger or any software?

I've tried different power sockets and to reinstall the game, but neither made any difference. I have not yet consulted the computer company. The computer is a newly bought Acer Aspire V7-582PG (NX.MTCED.006).

Also, whenever I turn World of Warcraft off the charger works pretty well, but lately the same problem has occured when doing nothing but browsing the net as well.

Comment: This is a hardware issue.  If its under warranty report the problem to the OEM and act accordingly.  If the problem happens only when you are using a browser then its not a overheating problem.  **Even if its caused by the heat the problem shouldn't happen.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitely sounds like a hardware problem.  It could be a number of things, but it sounds like a heat issue.  When you play WoW, the computer requires more power to power the processor, graphics card, sound, disk, etc.  As you play and more power is being drawn, the metal - most likely in the charger - is expanding from the heat and severing the electrical connection.  Since the power stops being drawn, the metal cools and shrinks, creating the connection again.  This cycle of expanding and contracting is probably causing the charger to repeatedly connect and disconnect.

The problem is definitely in the charger, or the socket the charger connects to on the laptop.  Either way, you should call the manufacturer for service.